# polymorphism in vector subsetting of Rcpp

Tags: rcpp, subset

Here is one R method I'd like to translate into c++ to speed things up

```
setMethod("[[", signature=signature(x="ncdfFlowSet"),
               definition=function(x, i, j, use.exprs = TRUE, ...)
{
  #subset by j
  if(!missing(j)){
    if(is.character(j)){
      j <- match(j, localChNames)
      if(any(is.na(j)))
        stop("subscript out of bounds")
    }  

    fr@parameters <- fr@parameters[j, , drop = FALSE]
    localChNames <- localChNames[j]
  }

  #other stuff

})
```

Kevin's nice work on [vector subsetting](http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/subsetting/) makes my life a lot easier for this `j` subsetting

```
    // [[Rcpp::export]]
    Rcpp::S4 readFrame(Rcpp::S4 x
                        , std::string sampleName
                        , Rcpp::RObject j_obj
                        , bool useExpr
                        )
    {
        Rcpp::Environment frEnv = x.slot("frames");
        Rcpp::S4 frObj = frEnv.get(sampleName);
        Rcpp::S4 fr = Rcpp::clone(frObj);

          //get local channel names
          Rcpp::StringVector colnames = x.slot("colnames");

          Rcpp::StringVector ch_selected;
         /*
          * subset by j if applicable
          */
         int j_type = j_obj.sexp_type();
         //creating j index used for subsetting colnames and pdata
         Rcpp::IntegerVector j_indx;

         if(j_type == STRSXP)//when character vector
         {
             ch_selected = Rcpp::StringVector(j_obj.get__());
             unsigned nCol = ch_selected.size();
             j_indx = Rcpp::IntegerVector(nCol);
             //match ch_selected to colnames
            for(unsigned i = 0 ; i < nCol; i ++)
            {
                const Rcpp::internal::string_proxy<STRSXP> &thisCh = ch_selected(i);
                Rcpp::StringVector::iterator match_id = std::find(colnames.begin(), colnames.end(), thisCh);
                if(match_id == colnames.end()){
                    std::string strCh = Rcpp::as<std::string>(thisCh);
                    Rcpp::stop("j subscript out of bounds: " + strCh);
                }else
                {
                    j_indx(i) = match_id - colnames.begin();
                }
            }
         }
         else if(j_type == NILSXP)//j is set to NULL in R when not supplied
         {
             ch_selected = colnames;
         }
         else if(j_type == LGLSXP)
         {
             Rcpp::LogicalVector j_val(j_obj.get__());
             ch_selected = colnames[j_val];
             #to convert numeric indices to integer
         }
         else if(j_type == INTSXP)
         {
             Rcpp::IntegerVector j_val(j_obj.get__());
             j_indx = j_val - 1; //convert to 0-based index
             ch_selected = colnames[j_indx];
         }
         else if(j_type == REALSXP)
         {
             Rcpp::NumericVector j_val(j_obj.get__());
             #to convert numeric indices to integer
         }
         else
             Rcpp::stop("unsupported j expression!");
        /*
         * subset annotationDataFrame (a data frame)
         * 
         */
         if(j_type != NILSXP)
         {
            Rcpp::S4 pheno = fr.slot("parameters");
            Rcpp::DataFrame pData = pheno.slot("data");

            Rcpp::CharacterVector pd_name = pData["name"];
            Rcpp::CharacterVector pd_desc = pData["desc"];
            Rcpp::NumericVector pd_range = pData["range"];
            Rcpp::NumericVector pd_minRange = pData["minRange"];
            Rcpp::NumericVector pd_maxRange = pData["maxRange"];

            Rcpp::DataFrame plist = Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("name") = pd_name[j_indx]
                                                        ,Rcpp::Named("desc") = pd_desc[j_indx]
                                                        ,Rcpp::Named("range") = pd_range[j_indx]
                                                        ,Rcpp::Named("minRange") = pd_minRange[j_indx]
                                                        ,Rcpp::Named("maxRange") = pd_maxRange[j_indx]
                                                        );
            pheno.slot("data") = plist;
         }
```

However `j` indexing in `R` usually allows different types of input (`character`, `logical` or `numeric`). I wonder if there is same kind of `polymorphic` mechanism (possibly through abstract vector pointer/reference) so that the redundant code(simply due to the different type of Rcpp::**Vector) for `[-subsetting` on the `data.frame` later on can be avoided.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We usually advocate separating the logic into a dispatch step, and a templated function step. So you should be able to solve your problem with something like the following:

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

template <typename T>
SEXP readFrame(Rcpp::S4 x, std::string sampleName, T const& j, bool useExpr) { 
    // use the typed 'j' expression
}

// [[Rcpp::export(subset)]]
SEXP readFrame_dispatch(Rcpp::S4 x, std::string sampleName, SEXP j, bool useExpr) 
    switch (TYPEOF(j)) {
    case INTSXP: return readFrame<IntegerVector>(x, sampleName, j, useExpr);
    case REALSXP: return readFrame<NumericVector>(x, sampleName, j, useExpr);
    case STRSXP: return readFrame<CharacterVector>(x, sampleName, j, useExpr);
    case LGLSXP: return readFrame<LogicalVector>(x, sampleName, j, useExpr);
    default: stop("Unsupported SEXP type");
    }
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

One of the design goals in Rcpp is to avoid runtime polymorphism whenever possible for speed reasons -- almost all polymorphism is done statically, and runtime lookup should ideally only occur once (except for occasional times when we're forced to call back to R for some routines).

The dispatch code is a bit ugly and mechanical, but allows for this 'style' of programming. The code becomes a lot more readable if 'dispatch' is separated from 'implementation' as well, as you can hide the dispatch ugliness in one location.

I do wonder if there is some macro magic that could reduce the code duplication in dispatch code of that form, though...